# check if imageview has been rotated — Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have an imageview that are being rotated PI/4 (radians) every time it's taped. 
That works fine with this code:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognize
{
if (tapRecognize == tapRecognizer)
{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imageview.transform, (M_PI / 4));
    [imageview setTransform:transform];
}
```

The tapRecognizer is asigned to the imageview.

Now, I want to check if the imageview has been rotated. This is my code:

```
if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(imageview.transform, rot45)) //rot45 is a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation variable which is set to M_PI / 4
{
    NSLog("Rotated");
}
```

That works fine for the first tap, when it has been rotated 45°. But I want to be able to check when it has been taped two times, which means that it has been rotated 90°. And so on. I want different actions on each rotation-angle. How can I check that?

Sorry if the question is unclear

Comment: `else if (CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform(imageview.transform, rot90)) { ... }` etc.

Comment: no, I forgot to mention, rot45 is a CGAffineTransformMakeRotation variable which is set to M_PI / 4. SO there is no rot90

Comment: @WilhelpMichaelsen And what prevents you from creating one?

Comment: i've tried. But since I'm comparing the transform of the imageview (which is M_PI / 4) whit the rot45 (which also is M_PI / 4, I can't create rot90 with M_PI / 2 because then it wont be the same as the imageviews transformation

Comment: Why not? 45 + 45 = 90, pi / 4 + pi / 4 = pi / 2, isn't it? Or is `CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform()` too dumb to put up with floating-point rounding errors?

Comment: I just think it compares the start transforming of the imageview which is M_PI / 4. Then of course if I tap it again it has rotated 90° but I dont think CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform reads the physical transformation of the imageview

Comment: Do you **think** that or did you **read it in the docs?** Don't make assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Devise a scheme to map the tag property to rotation. On every rotation update the tag value.

Comment: can you please explain a little bit deeper? I would really appreciate it